# Как заставить работать xDebug с Web Api?

Tags: api, phpstorm, openserver, xdebug

Добрый день.

Установлен и настроен **xDebug** на основном домене и поддоменах: **site.ru**, **admin.site.ru**, **mobile.site.ru**

При отладке страниц, он работает нормально. Использую **phpstorm 8.02** + **openserver 5.2.2**

Есть еще домен третьего уровня **api.site.ru**
Через этот поддомен на сайте успешно работает Web Api. Когда ставлю точку останова и пытаюсь отладить кросс-доменный ajax запрос (*с site.ru на api.site.ru*), то **xDebug** его не видит и пропускает мимо.

Для запуска **xDebug** использую https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Пробовал также https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

Он работает только при запуске в пределах одного домена.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема из за того, что ajax запрос идёт с другого домена, поэтому не срабатывает **xDebug**? Как это решить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем проблема решена.

Как оказалось js почему-то не отправлял куки со значением **XDEBUG_SESSION**, который необходим для работы с xDebug. В моём случае, на стороне js отрабатывал angular, который должен был посылать эти самые куки. А так как ide у меня была phpstorm и значение xDebug прямо установлено как PHPSTORM, то моя кука выглядела так: **XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM**

Первый результат в поиске сразу выдал ответ-решение на SO, почему браузер не отправляет куки вместе с запросом:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064791/http-doesnt-send-cookie-in-requests